# Taking away from nearest 10

Tags: python

Okay, i have made my code so that a user can input 7 numbers and times them by 1 for the odd index numbers and 3 for the even:

```
num = str(input("Please enter 7 numbers")
length = len(num)
while length < 7 or length ? 7:
    num = input("Only enter 7 numbers")
string = ''
for t in range(1,8):
    if t % 2 == 0:
        string += str(t * 3)
     else:   
         string += str(t) + ' '
 print(string)
```

This works fine, but now i need to add all the numbers up and take it away from the highest 10 so for example, all the numbers add up to 53 i need to take that away from 60 which leaves me 7, that will be my eight number, then after i have got that number i print it out, how do i get it to add the numbers up and the take it away from the highest 10 and output the difference of the two into the numbers i already have?

Thanks 
Brad

Comment: No, that _doesn't_ work fine. You have a couple of syntax errors; your input stuff won't work properly; and you aren't doing arithmetic on the  user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
def take_away_from_nearest(number, nearest):
    return nearest - (number % nearest)
```

Usage:

```
>>> take_away_from_nearest(53, 10)
7
```

**edit:**
If I understand you correctly, this would be the entire code:

```
while True:
    # this is just an easy way to keep asking until the input is correct
    num = input("Please enter 7 numbers: ")
    if len(num) == 7:
        break
weird_sum = 0 #here's where we're gonna sum up the numbers; the "eighth number"
for index, character in enumerate(num):
    if index % 2 == 0: # index is odd, so count the character thrice
        print(3 * int(character))
        weird_sum += 3 * int(character)
    else: # index is even
        print(int(character))
        weird_sum += int(character)
print(10 - (weird_sum % 10)) # 10 minus (weird_sum modulo 10)
# and finally, adding them all up and checking whether it ends with 0:
print((10-(weird_sum % 10) + weird_sum) % 10 == 0) # prints True
```

Comment: For this to work, would the user using this need to input the awnser in to the def? Sorry im new to coding

Comment: @Brad364 Not sure I understand you correctly, try my edit.

Comment: Im confused because i dont really understand whats happening there sorry

Comment: @Brad364 I'll comment it, give me a minute.

Comment: @Brad364: This code assumes the user is inputting a string of 7 digits with no spaces in between them.

Comment: @PM2Ring That's exactly how it's "working" in the question, isn't it?

Comment: Sure, apart from the syntax errors, and the fact that Brad's doing arithmetic on `t` instead of the input numbers. I made my comment because it's not clear if that's what Brad wants, or if he expects the code to work on multi-digit numbers, though.

Comment: Ill write you the question. I need to get the user to input 7 numbers (making this as efficient as possible while sticking to a GCSE level) then i need to times all the even index numbers by 3 and odd ones by 1 and print them out. Then i need to make an eight number by adding all the digits up (After they have been multiplied) and take it away from the nearest 10, then after that i need to check its valid by add every number up including the eighth and it should end up with a sum with zero on the end. I need to do this at a GCSE stranded

Comment: @Brad364: Ok. That sounds like a checksum algorithm, so you _do_ want the user to input a string of 7 digits with no spaces in between.

Comment: Yes, thats what i want

Comment: @Brad364 That algorithm makes no sense. Assume the 7 numbers add up to a number `x`. The last digit of `x` will be capital `X`. The eighth number will 10 minus that last digit, so `10-X`. And finally, the sum of the 7 numbers (ending in `X`) plus the eighth number (`10-X`)  will always sum up to some multiple of 10. This checksum will accept any string of 7 digits.

Comment: Sorry thats confused me, i just need to get 7 numbers as a string, then multiply them by 3 and 1 (odd index number times by 1 and even times by 2) then add them up and take it away from the nearest 10

Comment: That is in the code. `print(10 - (weird_sum % 10))` prints that. This is my final comment here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number, `x`, which is equal to 53, then going up should be `math.ceil(x)` except that `math.ceil()` rounds for `1`.  To account for that, we divide by 10, use `math.ceil()`, and then multiply by 10 again:

```
import math
rounded_up = math.ceil(x / 10) * 10
result = rounded_up - x
```

Comment: Okay, but i just found a error i dont know how to fix, i ran my code but i didnt enter 7 numbers, it did what i wanted and printed only enter 7 numbers, however when i entered 7 numbers it just carried on looping. Fix please?

Comment: That's because you aren't updating `length` each time.  You start out with it equal to `len(num)`, but you don't update it when you change num.  You should change your `while` condition to `while len(num) != 7:`

Answer (score 0):

Brad could you clarify your question? Also your above code does not work.

Missing a bracket on the first line and this isn't valid `while length < 7 or length ? 7:`

Comment: @Brad364: What do you expect `length ? 7` to do?

Comment: Oh thats a mistake shouldnt it be     while length < 7 or length > 7:

Comment: @Brad364: Correct! But L3viathan has shown you a better way to do that.

Comment: His way confused me, i'm new to this